# ¿Cómo puedo implementar SOAP en mi API rest con Express?

Tags: nodejs, api, express, soap, restful

Tengo mi apiRest la cual funciona perfectamente como lo deseo pero tengo otra api SOAP que debo consultar de la cual sólo tengo esto

```
<!-- Url: http://0.0.0.0/testConsulta/servicio.php?wsdl -->


<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ser="http:/0.0.0.0/testConsulta/servicio.php?wsdl">

   <soapenv:Header/>

   <soapenv:Body>

      <ser:creditosVencidos soapenv:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"/>

   </soapenv:Body>

</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Cómo puedo implementar esto en mi apiRest o que me recomiendan para poder consultar el SOAP desde mi apiRest con Express.

Answer (score 1):

Podrías usar [`node-soap`](https://github.com/vpulim/node-soap) de la siguiente manera:

```
var soap = require('soap');
var url = 'http://0.0.0.0/testConsulta/servicio.php?wsdl';
var args = {name: 'value'};
soap.createClient(url, function(err, client) {
  client.MyFunction(args, function(err, result) {
      console.log(result);
  });
});
```

En la documentación también hay ejemplos de como utilizarlo con [`express`](https://github.com/vpulim/node-soap#soaplistenserver-path-services-wsdl---create-a-new-soap-server-that-listens-on-path-and-provides-services).

Answer (score 0):

Utiliza `request`.

```
var request = require('request');
request.post(
{
  url:'http://webservice',
  body : datosEnvio,
  headers: {'Content-Type': 'text/xml'}
},
function (error, response, body) {        
  if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
      var result = body;
      res.status(200).send(result)
  }
  else{
      console.log(error)
      res.status(response.statusCode).send("Error")
  }
});
```